# What spectrum of light can the NOIR camera detect/read?

Tags: camera, picamera

Trying to establish what the NOIR camera can detect. We are more interested in the IR range of light that is possible. Specifically, we are using the NOIR in a dark environment (shutting out light) and are trying to see the difference in an apple's IR reading over time. In other studies that have looked at IR and fruit, they have cited looking at a specific range of wavelengths. ex: 400-1100 nm

How do we know what range is possible for the NOIR?

Answer (score 1):

You could expect some IR sensitivity up to about [1000nm](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-69389/l/raspberry-pi-noir-camera-module-v2-8-megapixel-sony-imx219-image-sensor). Note that the sensor in the NOIR cam is not optimized for IR, it just has the IR filter removed. As a result, its sensitivity to IR is much worse than to visible light. You can expect it to be something like this (note the picture is from a different camera):

[image]